# Composer update probleme on cpanel for symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php, cpanel

I have a problem for a symfony app when I try to install dependencies with composer :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.12] require composer-runtime-api >=2.1 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle 6.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.12].
```

Composer version I have on cpanel : 2.0.8
I didn't upgrade composer to the last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
symfony/framework-bundle[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.12] require composer-runtime-api >=2.1 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

That line basically tells you that Symfony in v6 requires any Composer version equal or above 2.1, and you are currently using Composer v2.0. Please update Composer itself, for example by using `composer self-update`

Comment: Thank you for your response but I don't have the permission :  `[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:
  Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written.
  rename(/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: I found a solution ! I download composer ([link](https://getcomposer.org/download/)) in the folder where is my code. Now I have a file composer.phar and I can execute ./composer.phar install/update without problem and with the last composer version.

Comment: Besides that: why do you need to have Composer on that server anyways?

Comment: To to install the symfony dependencies of my project

Comment: Why not install them during the deployment to avoid that Composer needs to be run on your application server?

Comment: Yes I will make that in the future